# Undo Use Theirs and Mark as Resolved - SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

*Hypothetically* -- not that I did this -- let's say someone I know updated their working copy of a file, saw conflicts, hastily clicked "use theirs" then quickly marked as resolved...

Is there any way to undo that and get back the couple of hundred lines of code that I.. er... I mean someone lost...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You've lost it.

When you..r friend.. saw the conflicts there would be 2 files on disk with both revisions changes in them. When you clicked 'use theirs' you'd have overwritten your WC file with the revision from one of those files. But, when you clicked 'resolved' you deleted both the temporary revision files.

So, if you're lucky they might be recoverable with some undelete software and then you can unpick your WC with those changes (try reverting the the previous revision and then applying the file as a patch)

Comment: Sweet.  While this was an .aspx page "my friend's" missing code was client side javascript.  So using the chrome cache viewer from Nirsoft (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html) I was able to dig through the cache and find most of the missing code.  I should really lecture "my friend" though on not acting hastily.

Answer (score 30):

Maybe this may help other people that have a similar problem: we have this situation and we found the deleted file in the Recycle bin. We actually found the .mine and .theirs files and we were able to recover the changes

Comment: I had a similar situation. I went into the directory with the resolved file, hit Ctrl+Z, and the .mine and .theirs magically reappeared from the Recycle Bin!

Comment: @Jefrey Solis - there is a special place for you in heaven, you had just saved me three days of work!
Tanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

If you use `Eclipse` to write your code, right-click your file, go to `Compare with` and check `Local history`. Then you should see a list of local copies of the file with timestamps. If you double click any of them it will open it in compare mode where you can view it(and copy your lost work).

Similar IDEs might or might not have some kind of local versioning/backup.

Comment: Not eclipse, but another IDE with local history. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You almost lost the data but still there is a copy in Recycle bin. You can restore from their if you have not empty the recycle bin. Face the same issue but find it in Recyle Bin.

Answer (score 2):

If this only change in the local working copy where you do the merge and commited that it's too late, cause *use theirs* means to say yes i will theirs and will smash away my own changes. 
If the changes had been done during a merge of a branch into trunk than the changes exist on the branch furthermore. Than you can get back them.